# Radioboxfor model binding with class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, radiobuttonfor

I have a class Contact:

```
public class Contact
{
  public int Id { get;set; }
  public Boolean DefaultYN {get;set; }
  public string AdrType { get; set; }
  public string Street {get; set; }
  public string Town {get; set; }
  public string HouseNr { get; set; }
  public string PostCd { get; set; }     
}
```

I have a VieModel

```
public class ContactVm
{
    public Contact SelectedContact { get; set; }
    public Contact SelectedInvoiceContact { get;set; }
    public List<Contact> ContactList { get; set; }
}
```

I have a strongly - typped View

```
@model MvcBeaWeb.Models.ContactVm
<!-- Address Div -->
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "OrderSummary"))
{   
  <div id="deliveryAddressTab" class="deliveryAddressTab" style="margin: 10px 3px;">
    @foreach (var item in Model.ContactList)
    {                            
      <div style="display: inline-block; float: left;">
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.SelectedContact, item, new {@checked = true ,id = "item" + item.Id })
      </div>
      <div id="@item.Id" style="float: left; margin-left: 10px; font-weight: 500;">
        <span class="spnTown">@item.PostCd @item.Town</span>
      </div>                
    }
  </div>
}
```

So you see that for each `Contact` from ContactList I create one radiobutton for the `SelectedContact` property of the model. But as this is complex type (Contact object) when I click the input button and I'm navigated to index action of my OrderSummary controller

```
public ActionResult Index (ContactVm contactVm)
{
  /* .... */
}
```

my contactVm  parameter is empty and model binding it seems is not working

Comment: By Default this is calling Get Function for your action can you decorate your action method with HttpPost and Use FormMethod.Post in Html.BeginForm("Index", "OrderSummary").

Comment: You cant bind a radio button (or any other control) to a complex object. And why are you setting `@checked = true` which means that the last radio button will always be selected

Comment: Use @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "OrderSummary", FormMethod.Post)) and as stephen said you cant relate for complex object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Model Binder does not have enough information to rehydrate the Contact class.  For each property of the ViewModel there needs to be a value provided in the request (e.g forms, querystring etc..) to bind up the whole model, so in your example it won't work.

I am assuming you are loading the Contact list from storage. (e.g DB)

I would expose a property on the viewModel for SelectedContactId and use this as the **RadioButtonFor** method, and use the ID of the Contact in the list to be value of the radio button:

```
Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedContactId, item.Id )
```

Then when you load in your View model, you can load the contacts back from storage, and locate the Contact by ID

Comment: Yes the first time I did it the same way. The problem is that I need apart from the id of the address I need also the AdrType (invoice, delivery). So  what do you think how can I achieve this!  IS it possible to bind this radiobutton for somehow related with these two properties. Which are the corrected ways to achieve this.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with Addresstype, is it a choice for the user?  I would ask this is another questions and give more detail.

Comment: You see that my class Contact has two properties public class Contact
-  Id { get;set; } and property AdrType { get; set; };  Somehow the radio button should be connected to these two properties.

Comment: Well that makes little sense :), a radio button is for a boolean choice, so how can a single button make two decisions?  If your still having trouble, start a new question explaining the expected behaviour.